# Create a SQL Server table by importing fields from two tables using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, one filled with data from an Excel sheet (say `Ts` table), and one with file id and file name (say `Tm` table) from the Excel file.

I want to create a third table with all columns from the `Ts` table and file id column of the `Tm` table (file id column of `Tm` is not present in `Ts`) along with an identity column. And I want to create it using a stored procedure.

I tried the following the code which didn't work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ToInsertTx(@fileid INT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @fileid = (SELECT FileId FROM Tm)

    (INSERT @fileid as fileid INTO Tx,
    INSERT RowNo identity(101, 1))

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT * INTO Tx FROM Ts)
END
```

Comment: Can you explain bit further? Better to show some picture of your input and output tables

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @Khorshed: we positively discourage images of data here. Data should be shown as text, since images are not compatible with screen-readers, clipboards or search engines.

Comment: @halfer got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this considering the fact that you have data for only one excel file in Ts table and there is one record for that file in Tm table :

```
    select * into Tx from Ts

    alter table Tx 
    add FileId int

    update Tx set FileId=(select top 1 FileId from Tm)

    alter table Tx add RowNo INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Comment: thanks @sumankabir...when i execute this procedure it asks for the parameter value fileid

Comment: i am getting fileid column created but value it is showing is null for all field

Comment: @mrityunjaykumar - I don't see any need of stored procedure here, i removed it, please check the update sql now.

Comment: hey @sumankabir thanks a lot...it worked..the stored procedure too..but i cant alter the order of column...i wanted to make the identity column first one...if you can help with that please...that will be all..thanks a lot.

Comment: You can't make the identity column at first using the sql. You have to make it in the table design window. You can get more info [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/change-column-order-in-a-table). Please mark the answer as useful(upvote) and accept the answer.

Comment: hey @sumankabir....can i get one last help please...as i have to alter table Tx because i have a new dataset into Ts table and also new FileId. how can i do that

Comment: I would like to post you a new question for this instead. Please be noted: in the new post, please describe well the scenario. As i told that the solution i gave you only considering the fact `you have data for only one excel file in Ts table and there is one record for that file in Tm table`. But if you have now different scenario, please describe well with example and let the community help you. You can let me know the url of your post. Also ensure that you have tried yourself to achieve this, because this site is not for doing works for others!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are looking for exactly.. unless you have something to link the two tables together I assume that you only have one value in the Tm table?

If so you could do a cross join:

```
select
    Tm.fileid
    ,Ts.*
into
    NewTableName
from
    Tm cross join Ts
```

If there is more than one value in the Tm table you will need to have some way of knowing which rows relate to which.  Or if this is part of a ETL process you might add a column that marks when a record has been processed or something.

cross join joins all rows from one table to all rows of another - it crates all permutations.. but probably you need to give more info in the question :)